# How to use relative import without doing python -m?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, relative-import

I have a folder like this

```
/test_mod
    __init__.py
    A.py
    test1.py
    /sub_mod
        __init__.py
        B.py
        test2.py
```

And I want to use relatives imports in `test1` and `test2` like this

```
#test1.py
from . import A
from .sub_mod import B
...

#test2.py
from .. import A
from . import B
...
```

While I develop `test1` or `test2` I want that those imports to work while I am in the IDLE, that is if I press `F5` while working in `test2` that every work fine, because I don't want to do `python -m test_mod.sub_mod.test2` for instance.

I already check this
[python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Looking at that, I tried this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and not __package__:
    __package__ = "test_mod.sub_mod"
from .. import A
from . import B
```

But that didn't work, it gave this error:

```
SystemError: Parent module 'test_mod.sub_mod' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I found this solution

```
#relative_import_helper.py
import sys, os, importlib

def relative_import_helper(path,nivel=1,verbose=False): 
    namepack = os.path.dirname(path)
    packs = []
    for _ in range(nivel):
        temp = os.path.basename(namepack)
        if temp:
            packs.append( temp )
            namepack = os.path.dirname(namepack)
        else:
            break
    pack = ".".join(reversed(packs))
    sys.path.append(namepack)
    importlib.import_module(pack)
    return pack
```

and I use as

```
#test2.py
if __name__ == "__main__" and not __package__:
    print("idle trick")
    from relative_import_helper import relative_import_helper
    __package__ = relative_import_helper(__file__,2)

from .. import A
...
```

then I can use relatives import while working in the IDLE.