# Not sure if I should use relative imports or add parent dir to sys.path

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

I have a package with the following hierarchy

```
my_package/__init__.py
           script_a.py
           scripts_dir/__init__.py
                       script_b.py
           my_package/__init__.py
                      module_a.py
                      module_b.py
```

module_a and module_b contain function and class definitions that I am using in script_a and script_b (which are stand alone scripts and contain a main)

When I import something from let's say module_a.py in my script_a.py everything is fine.

My problems are

- I cannot figure out how to use relative imports to import something from module_a or module_b to script_b.py
- I am not sure if I am supposed to use relative imports or if it makes more sense to add my_package to sys.path and then use something like
  `from my_package.module_a import the_funky_func`
- I want to avoid having to call the interpreter with the `-m` argument

**update**

From the answers I have found so far in SO I have concluded that I have 3 options

- write a setup to include the package to my PYTHONPATH so that all scripts regardless of where they are can call the modules
- use the `-m` argument when invoking the interpreter
- do some sys.path hack

Is there another option that I am not aware of?

Comment: for the last part you can check my solution to that: [how-to-use-relative-import-without-doing-python-m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855800/how-to-use-relative-import-without-doing-python-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myproject/
        |--package1
              |--\__init__.py
              |--script_a.py
              |--script_b.py
        |--package2
              |--module_a.py
              |--module_b.py
```

You can use below 2 lines appends `myproject` path to sys path. It can avoid relative import and avoid `-m` in the command line

```
import sys
import sys.path.append("/absolute/path/to/your/myproject")
```

In `myproject`  file `script_a.py`, if you import `module_a.py`  it would look like

```
import sys
import sys.path.append("/absolute/path/to/your/myproject")
import package2.module_a as ma
```

Comment: Would you recommend that over adding the package path to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: yes. the scope is the project itself, not the whole system